# WebRootPath and TestServer

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit.net

I have a XUnit test project with the following structure:

- \MyApp.Rest

  - \wwwroot
- \MyApp.Rest.Tests

  - Project reference to "MyApp.Rest"

`_environment.WebRootPath` in my integration tests is always null and I have some code in the tested project that depends on that value. I know I can set the value manually in the TestStartup. I am wondering if there is a better way to set the value other than hard-coding the path (`C:\...\MyApp.Rest\wwwroot`)?

```
public TestStartup(IHostingEnvironment environment, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
    _environment = environment;
    _environment.WebRootPath = "ugly_hardcoded_path_to_wwwroot"

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{_environment.EnvironmentName}.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Comment: Unit tests don't have external dependencies under test, everything is mocked. TestServer is for **integration** tests where you tests multiple (or all) systems at once

Comment: These are indeed integration tests, I edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

I came accross the same issue in my integration test. I use `TestServer` class in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost`

Here is how i configure the WebrootPath :

```
_server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseWebRoot(@"The path i want to use")
                .UseStartup<Startup>());
_client = _server.CreateClient();
```